# supervisordで4つ目のタスクが表示されない

Tags: python, supervisord

始めまして。
supervisordを利用しました。
/etc/supervisord.confというファイルにprogramを記載しました。

programを4つほど登録しました。
しかしながら、アルファベット順で4番目のものがどうしてもWebのコンソールに表示されません。

Webのコンソールと言うのは、http_portで指定して開くものです。
※正式名がわかりません。が「(c) 2006 Chris McDonough」の記載がされてるWebページです。

コマンドは間違ってなさそうです。

```
[program:program_name]
command=python /home/hoge/hoge.py some param
startsecs = 5
user = root
redirect_stderr = true
stderr_logfile = /var/log/supervisor/program/hoge-stderr.log
stdout_logfile = /var/log/supervisor/program/hoge-stdout.log
```

のように行っています。

ご教授お願いします。

全部です。
↓

```
[supervisord]
http_port=/var/tmp/supervisor.sock ; (default is to run a UNIX domain socket server)
http_port=0.0.0.0:8888 ; (alternately, ip_address:port specifies AF_INET)
;http_port=127.0.0.1:9001  ; (alternately, ip_address:port specifies AF_INET)
;sockchmod=0700              ; AF_UNIX socketmode (AF_INET ignore, default 0700)
;sockchown=nobody.nogroup     ; AF_UNIX socket uid.gid owner (AF_INET ignores)
;umask=022                   ; (process file creation umask;default 022)
logfile=/var/log/supervisor/supervisord.log ; (main log file;default $CWD/supervisord.log)
logfile_maxbytes=50MB       ; (max main logfile bytes b4 rotation;default 50MB)
logfile_backups=10          ; (num of main logfile rotation backups;default 10)
loglevel=info               ; (logging level;default info; others: debug,warn)
pidfile=/var/run/supervisord.pid ; (supervisord pidfile;default supervisord.pid)
nodaemon=false              ; (start in foreground if true;default false)
minfds=1024                 ; (min. avail startup file descriptors;default 1024)
minprocs=200                ; (min. avail process descriptors;default 200)

;nocleanup=true              ; (don't clean up tempfiles at start;default false)
;http_username=user          ; (default is no username (open system))
;http_password=123           ; (default is no password (open system))
;childlogdir=/tmp            ; ('AUTO' child log dir, default $TEMP)
;user=chrism                 ; (default is current user, required if root)
;directory=/tmp              ; (default is not to cd during start)
;environment=KEY=value       ; (key value pairs to add to environment)

;[unix_http_server]
;file = /tmp/supervisor.sock
;chmod = 0777
;chown = dev:dev

[supervisorctl]
serverurl=unix:///var/tmp/supervisor.sock ; use a unix:// URL  for a unix socket
;serverurl=http://127.0.0.1:9001 ; use an http:// url to specify an inet socket
;serverurl=http://127.0.0.1:3331 ; use an http:// url to specify an inet socket
;username=chris              ; should be same as http_username if set
;password=123                ; should be same as http_password if set
;prompt=mysupervisor         ; cmd line prompt (default "supervisor")


; App appname Program ================================
; hoge 3
[program:hoge_appname]
command=python /home/username/work/some_program.py start 3 demo_appname /var/www/django/demo/appname/appname
startsecs = 5
user = root
redirect_stderr = true
stderr_logfile = /var/log/supervisor/Program/hoge_appname-stderr.log
stdout_logfile = /var/log/supervisor/Program/hoge_appname-stdout.log

; bar 4
[program:bar_appname]
command=python /home/username/work/some_program.py start 4 demo_appname /var/www/django/demo/appname/appname
startsecs = 5
user = root
redirect_stderr = true
stderr_logfile = /var/log/supervisor/Program/bar_appname-stderr.log
stdout_logfile = /var/log/supervisor/Program/bar_appname-stdout.log


; appnametwo Program ================================
; hoge
[program:hoge_appnametwo]
command=python /home/username/work/some_program.py start 3 demo_appnametwo /var/www/django/demo/appnametwo/appname
startsecs = 5
user = root
redirect_stderr = true
stderr_logfile = /var/log/supervisor/Program/hoge_appnametwo-stderr.log
stdout_logfile = /var/log/supervisor/Program/hoge_appnametwo-stdout.log


; bar 4
[program:bar_appnametwo]
command=python /home/username/work/some_program.py start 4 demo_appnametwo /var/www/django/demo/appnametwo/appname
startsecs = 5
user = root
redirect_stderr = true
stderr_logfile = /var/log/supervisor/Program/bar_appnametwo-stderr.log
stdout_logfile = /var/log/supervisor/Program/bar_appnametwo-stdout.log



; The below sample program section shows all possible program subsection values,
; create one or more 'real' program: sections to be able to control them under
; supervisor.

;[program:theprogramname]
;command=/bin/cat            ; the program (relative uses PATH, can take args)
;priority=999                ; the relative start priority (default 999)
;autostart=true              ; start at supervisord start (default: true)
;autorestart=true            ; retstart at unexpected quit (default: true)
;startsecs=10                ; number of secs prog must stay running (def. 10)
;startretries=3              ; max # of serial start failures (default 3)
;exitcodes=0,2               ; 'expected' exit codes for process (default 0,2)
;stopsignal=QUIT             ; signal used to kill process (default TERM)
;stopwaitsecs=10             ; max num secs to wait before SIGKILL (default 10)
;user=chrism                 ; setuid to this UNIX account to run the program
;log_stdout=true             ; if true, log program stdout (default true)
;log_stderr=true             ; if true, log program stderr (def false)
;logfile=/var/log/cat.log    ; child log path, use NONE for none; default AUTO
;logfile_maxbytes=1MB        ; max # logfile bytes b4 rotation (default 50MB)
;logfile_backups=10          ; # of logfile backups (default 10)
```

Comment: 問題が再現する設定ファイルをまるまる載せることはできますか? (質問は後から[edit]できます)

Comment: entoさんありがとうございます。

文字数制限があるため、
質問を編集しました。

また、申し訳ありませんが、人名やアプリ名はそのままだとまずいので別名に置き換えています。

Comment: 「アルファベット順で4番目」とは hoge_appnametwo の事でしょうか？ また、実行されないプログラムのエラーログファイルに何か手がかりになる様なものは出力されていないのでしょうか？

Comment: heliac2001さん

ご返答ありがとうございます。
名前を変えてしまったため、アルファベットが変わってしまいましたが、
3番目のhoge_appnametwoが失敗しております。

エラーログにファイルも生成されておらず手がかりがつかめてないです。

Comment: 自己解決しました。
echo_supervisord_conf > /etc/supervisord.conf
をした後で、
再度設定すると大丈夫でした。
なぜかWebコンソールの背景色とか見た目が変わったのも気になります。

Answer (score 1):

```
echo_supervisord_conf > /etc/supervisord.conf
```

した後、再度設定すると直りました。

<sup>-- 質問者[shinriyoさん](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/7934/shinriyo)自身による[コメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/5579/supervisord%E3%81%A74%E3%81%A4%E7%9B%AE%E3%81%AE%E3%82%BF%E3%82%B9%E3%82%AF%E3%81%8C%E8%A1%A8%E7%A4%BA%E3%81%95%E3%82%8C%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84#comment4374_5579)より。</sup>